# Unity3d Writing to file path on mac access denied

Tags: c#, macos, file, unity-game-engine

I try to save a test1.csv to a folder path and Unity says access denied:

How can I give permissions on Mac OS Sierra? I already did CMD+I and gave "everyone" read+write for file and folder but it did not help.. google not helping me out either.

How can I allow permissions? Thank you in advance!

```
TextWriter tw1 = new StreamWriter ("/Users/X/testunity/test1.csv, true);
tw1.WriteLine ("testfile");
tw1.Close ();


UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/Users/X/testunity/' is denied.
System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean anonymous, FileOptions options) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:259)
System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream:.ctor (string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor (System.String path, Boolean append, System.Text.Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/StreamWriter.cs:124)
System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor (System.String path, Boolean append)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.StreamWriter:.ctor (string,bool)
LoggerM.LateUpdate () (at Assets/Scripts/LoggerM.cs:137)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always write to the `Application.persistentDataPath+folder` path in Unity. This will guarantee that the code will be compatible with most of the platforms Unity supports.

```
string path = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "data");
path = Path.Combine(path, "test1.csv");

//Create Directory if it does not exist
if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(path)))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(path));
}

using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path))
{
    writer.WriteLine("testfile");
}
```

Personally, `File.WriteAllBytes` to write to a file so I would recommed that unless you want to write to the file line by line.

```
string path = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "data");
path = Path.Combine(path, "test1.csv");

//Create Directory if it does not exist
if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(path)))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(path));
}

byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("testfile");
File.WriteAllBytes(path, data);
```

Comment: Unfortunately the original version was with Application.persistentDataPath and it results in the same error. I also tried your code snippet 1:1 and also says access denied :(

Comment: Ok, just use what's in my first answer. Copy it like it is. It should work. If not, use the second one but just copy it like it is. Don't change anything in it